# A doubt about an integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Suppose I have, $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{\delta(x)}{x}dx= ?$

Now If I think of its asymmetric integrand, then ans is $0.$, Otherwise, it is $1/0=\infty$. (Divergent!)

Which ans I should consider. Pl help.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is not convergent since $f(x)=1/x$ is not defined where $\delta(x)\neq0\iff x=0$.